# Get curvature and torsion of a curve represented with a amount of points

Tags: calculus, geometry, curves

I have $n$ curves in the 3d space, which I represented with a certain amount of points.

For every curve $i$, there is a vector $v_i$ with $m$ points which belong to the curve.
How can i get the torsion and the curvature of a curve through the vector $v_i$?

I thought about Spline interpolation to fit all curves and after calculate torsion and curvature but i'm not sure of this.

Comment: Try Theorems 2.3 and (2.5 or 2.6) in: Langer, Torsten, Alexander G. Belyaev, and Hans-Peter Seidel. "Asymptotic analysis of discrete normals and curvatures of polylines." *Proceedings of the 21st spring conference on Computer graphics*. ACM, 2005.